# Is this the right way to handle Exceptions in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, facebook

I'm using the function `countLikes()` to fetch URLs' Likes count from the Facebook API.

```
// Link.php

class Link
{

private $url;

public function __construct($url){
    $this->url = new Url($url);
}

public function getUrl(){
    return $this->url();
}

public function countLikes()
{
    global $config;

    $call = $config["facebook.api"]["baseurl"] .
            "/" .
            $config["facebook.api"]["version"] .
            "/?" .
            "id=" . $this->url->getEncodedUrl() .
            "&access_token=" . $config["facebook.api"]["key"];

    try {
        $response = Utils::curl($call);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LinkException("Unable to cURL Facebook API.", 0, $e);
    }

    if (is_array($response)) {
        if (array_key_exists("error", $response)) {
            throw new LinkException(
            "Facebook Graph API v2.2 error : "
            . $response["error"]["message"], $response["error"]["code"]
            );
        } elseif (isset($response["share"])) {
            $count = $response["share"]["share_count"];
        } else {
            $count = 0;
        }

        return $count;
    } else {
        throw new LinkException("Graph API Response is not an array");
    }
}
}
```

And this is how it's used :

```
$link = new Link("http://www.facebook.com");

try{
    $likes = $link->countLikes();
    echo "Link $link->getUrl()->getFullUrl() has $likes likes for the moment. <br>";
} catch(LinkException $e){
    do{
        $logger->add($e->getMessage());
    }while ($e = $e->getPrevious());
}
```

While this is working as it's supposed to do, I'm not happy with the way exceptions are treated and I'm not even sure this is the right way to do it. Is there a better way to manage exceptions and handle them?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Exceptions correctly, however its possible to catch more than one type of exception with the same try block. Instead of specifically catching the `LinkException` in your logging routine, you should probably just catch any `Exception`, but prefix the error string with the Exception's class.

I also recommend putting the declaration of the `$link` object inside the try block in case the `Url` class throws an exception from inside the `Link` class's constructor.

```
try {
    // execute code
    $foo = new Foo();
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    // log exceptions
    $logger->add( get_class( $e ) . ': ' . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Push your logging as high up in your application as possible so you are collecting all exceptions, not just your custom ones.

Comment: Yes. You are totally right sir. It's a good idea to add the declaration of `$link` in the `try` block. That will help me avoid multiple headaches as the code grows.  

By the way, all the exceptions I use are inheriting from a `BaseException` that prepends `__FILE__:__LINE__` to the messaage.  

As for `catch`-ing `Exception`, I will do that as a fallback and leave the `LinkException` there (at least) for documentation purposes. Do you think it's worth it?  

One last question, please : I create a new exception for every new class I create, is there a better strategy for doing this?

Comment: The `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are magic constants that refer to the file and line where they exist in the code, not where the exception occurred. To print the file and line where the exception occurred you have to call the public methods of the `Exception` class which are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: As far as the best way to design your exception handling system, there is not really a wrong way. You can base it on class, or you can do something more abstract like how the built in SPL exceptions have been designed. Personally, I extend the SPL exceptions and then group them by implementing class interfaces.